# Reading single string of json in swift ui

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

> I'm using this API http://shibe.online/api/shibes? although when i load it, all i see is a single link which is what i want to use but there is no variable identifier associated with it.

```
["https://cdn.shibe.online/shibes/be12be31e2c880b4ac6992b3bb02751211b6ee68.jpg"]
```

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct ShibeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fetcher = ShibeFetcher()

    var body: some View {
            AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: self.fetcher.shibe?.url ?? "")).resizable().scaledToFit()
    }
}

public class ShibeFetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published var shibe: ShibeRecievers?

    init(){
        load()
    }

    func load() {
        let url = URL(string: "http://shibe.online/api/shibes?")!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data,response,error) in
            do {
                if let d = data {
                    let webData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ShibeRecievers.self, from: d)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.shibe = webData
                    }
                }else {
                    print("No Data")
                }
            } catch {
                print ("Error here")
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}


struct ShibeRecievers: Codable {
    var url: String //Not sure how to store the link from the api
}
```

> The problem i have is storing the link from the api into my app and I can't find any json parsing documentation without variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json response is just an array of String. So you can decode it like this:

```
try! JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: d)
```

Completed version based on your current implementation:

```
struct ShibeView: View {
  @ObservedObject var fetcher = ShibeFetcher()

  var body: some View {
    Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: fetcher.shibe?.first ?? "https://i.imgur.com/epMSRQH.png")!)) ?? UIImage())
  }
}

public class ShibeFetcher: ObservableObject {
  @Published var shibe: [String]?

  init(){
    load()
  }

  func load() {
    let url = URL(string: "http://shibe.online/api/shibes?")!

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data,response,error) in
      do {
        if let d = data {
          let webData = try JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: d)
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.shibe = webData
          }
        }else {
          print("No Data")
        }
      } catch {
        print ("Error here")
      }

    }.resume()
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok i understand that part but now where would i store the url to be used to display the image.

Comment: I think you can use your current way to save the image urls. have you tried?

Comment: @PeterK See my edited answer to get the full version.